# how can replace unwanted character with space for fixed length input data using xslt

Tags: xslt

This is the input data:

```
F080111481513        1010592   820101400 29106135-AIDS Walk Atlanta & 52016083000000000005000.00E5USD    040801009262      Y000
```

(this is fixed length file)

I want to replace `&` with the space using xslt.

my file can contain multiple records.

Please help me how i can do this.

Comment: what you want output

Comment: How exactly do you intend to use a fixed-length, non-XML file as the input to XSLT?